# Since a selection list, how can I set the navigation sequentially?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I'm starting a new project in WPF and am now looking into using Prism. For now I'm simply trying to set up the navigation of the application using Prism. Unfortunately, my lack of experience with the framework makes it a bit difficult to get started.

To be more precise about my first challenge I have an application with a "navigation/menu" region and a "main" region.

In "navigation/menu" region, I have several checkboxes, in this case we have four of them, which represents a sequential navigation. I.E. we've selected View 2 and View 4.

[image]

So, when the user click Start, in "main" region must appear each view selected in that order. Check the below image, View 2 is first. Then when the user press next, must show View 4.

[image]

I mean on a more structural level..

if I could only get through the first steps..

Comment: yes, i mean that.. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism support TabControl Region Adapter, navigation can be done using standard `requestNavigation` method.

1. You need add all your tab content using `Region.Add` method to the region in your module's init phase.

   view:

   ```
   <TabControl prism:RegionManger.RegionName="tabRegion" />
   ```

   C# code:

   ```
   IRegionManager manager;
   manager.Regions["tabRegion"].Views.Add(Container.Resolve(typeof(YourViewType)));
   ```
2. In your viewModel, you should write you navigation command:

   ```
   public void NextView() {
       regionManager.RequestNavigation("tabRegion", new Uri("YourViewType", UriKind.Relative));
   }
   ```

   bind to your "next" button:

   ```
   <Button Command="{Binding NextViewCommand}" />
   ```
3. If you want to control whether user can navigate to next page, you can implement `INavigationAware` interface.
4. If you don't want lost data between navigation, you can make your view model has `ContainerMangedLifeCycle` or implement `IsNavigationTarget` method to return `true`.

Sorry for untested code sample, but you should get the point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class named ViewVM with a property IsSelected.  Must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. Add an `ObservableCollection<View>` named `Views` to your datacontext.  Populate it with new instances of ViewVM.
3. Put an ItemsControl in your Window, with ItemsSource set to `Views`.  The DataTemplate for the ItemsControl items should contain a CheckBox (with IsChecked bound to IsSelected) and a Label.
4. Add a TabControl to your Window, with ItemSource set to Views.  Add a Style for TabItem such that TabItems are only visible if `IsSelected` is true.

Following the above steps will give you a window containing a list of views with checkboxes, as you requested, and a TabControl displaying only the selected views.  Below is the XAML (I have tested this):

```
<StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Views}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Views}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>
            </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

This addresses the structural/design aspect and should give you a good start to creating your solution - you'll also need to create a custom control to use instead of the TabControl.  Instead of having tabs, your custom control should contain `Next` and `Previous` buttons to navigate between views.

Comment: your idea seems good. I've got just a doubt, so I do not have to use Navigation interfaces from PRISM anymore, right?